# Command for karma-jasmine to stop unit-test after first fail

Tags: unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Is there any command for karma-jasmine unit-test to stop the test when it encounters the first test fail. For example, in python the command is like:

```
py.test -x             # stop after first failure
py.test --maxfail=2    # stop after two failures
```

Currently I am using `node_modules/karma/bin/karma start` that run all the tests and stops only after everything is executed

Answer (score 0):

This would require creating a custom reporter, or changing the reporter in the karma-jasmine adapter to stop on spec failure as such:

```
this.specDone = function (specResult) 
  {
  var failure = specResult.failedExpectations.length;

  if (failure) 
    {
    suiteDone();
    jasmineDone();
    }
  }
```

**References**

- [jasmine.io: custom_reporter.js](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/custom_reporter.html)
- [karma-jasmine source: adapter.js](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine/blob/master/src/adapter.js)
- [Jasmine Issue #842:  Async reporter hooks](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/842)
- [Protractor Issue #1938: Find a good pattern for waiting for Jasmine Reporters](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1938)

Answer (score -3):

Alternatively you can just tell jasmine you want to run a specific Spec or Specs in a folder so you only are testing a subset of your tests and not running all in your suite.